# jQuery JSON to string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Instead of going JSON a json string and using $.parseJSON, I need to take my object and store it in a variable as string representing JSON.

(A library I'm dealing with expects a malformed JSON type so I need to mess around with it to get it to work.)

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Comment: Which library expects a malformed JSON string? :/

Comment: Stanford JavaScript Cryptography Library outputs and parses malformed JSON, the bug is bring worked on at the moment.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

**Edit:** You should use the json2.js library from Douglas Crockford instead of implementing the code below. It provides some extra features and better/older browser support.

Grab the json2.js file from: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

---

```
// implement JSON.stringify serialization
JSON.stringify = JSON.stringify || function (obj) {
    var t = typeof (obj);
    if (t != "object" || obj === null) {
        // simple data type
        if (t == "string") obj = '"'+obj+'"';
        return String(obj);
    }
    else {
        // recurse array or object
        var n, v, json = [], arr = (obj && obj.constructor == Array);
        for (n in obj) {
            v = obj[n]; t = typeof(v);
            if (t == "string") v = '"'+v+'"';
            else if (t == "object" && v !== null) v = JSON.stringify(v);
            json.push((arr ? "" : '"' + n + '":') + String(v));
        }
        return (arr ? "[" : "{") + String(json) + (arr ? "]" : "}");
    }
};

var tmp = {one: 1, two: "2"};
JSON.stringify(tmp); // '{"one":1,"two":"2"}'
```

Code from: http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2009/08/19/javascript-json-serialization/

Comment: I would recommend the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/json2.js) library instead of this function, because it doesn't handle correctly some types, like properties containing `undefined`, functions, (which are not a valid JSON values), Boolean objects (e.g. `new Boolean(true);`), or `NaN` which should be replaced with `null`, etc... also it doesn't support the additional optional arguments, the `replacer` function and the `spaces` number for indentation, which are [fully described](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.12.3) in the standard.

Comment: i think perhaps the json2 link should be: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Comment: Most browsers have a native JSON object these days, which includes parse and stringify methods. So just try `JSON.stringify({})` and see if you get `"{}"` without needing to include the above code. You can even pass in parameters to filter out keys or to do pretty-printing, e.g. `JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2}, null, 2)` puts a newline and 2 spaces in front of each key.

Comment: For the ones looking for a modern answer: JSON.stringify(); is implemented in all the browsers (desktop and mobile): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 38):

I use

```
$.param(jsonObj)
```

which gets me the string.

Comment: But this does not create JSON (and that was the question).

Comment: but this little code is doing all the title of the question requests :P

Answer (score 35):

Most browsers have a native `JSON` object these days, which includes `parse` and `stringify` methods. So just try `JSON.stringify({})` and see if you get `"{}"`. You can even pass in parameters to filter out keys or to do pretty-printing, e.g. `JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2}, null, 2)` puts a newline and 2 spaces in front of each key.

```
JSON.stringify({a:1,b:2}, null, 2)
```

gives

```
"{\n  \"a\": 1,\n  \"b\": 2\n}"
```

which prints as

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}
```

As for the messing around part of your question, use the second parameter. From http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/json.shtml :

> The replacer parameter can either be a function or an array of
>   String/Numbers. It steps through each member within the JSON object to
>   let you decide what value each member should be changed to. As a
>   function it can return:
>
> - A number, string, or Boolean, which replaces the property's original    value with the returned one.
> - An object, which is serialized then    returned. Object methods or functions are not allowed, and are    removed instead.
> - Null, which causes the property to be removed.
>
> As an array, the values defined inside it corresponds to the names of
>   the properties inside the JSON object that should be retained when
>   converted into a JSON object.

Answer (score 10):

The best way I have found is to use [jQuery JSON](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/)

Comment: because it is a jquery _plugin_ & not what's directly provided by jquery

Comment: @user01 but jquery doesn't include a way to do this (at least it didn't when I wrote this reply, not sure if it does now)

Comment: @DavidReynolds: yes of course, I understand:) I didn't intend any offence to you but just commented on this as a solution to problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the JSON to an object, then create your malformed JSON from the ajavscript object. This may not be the best performance-wise, tho.

Otherwise, if you only need to make very small changes to the string, just treat it as a string, and mangle it using standard javascript.