# Format of Javascript Object of Arrays to save as C# dictionary for WCF

Tags: c#, javascript, wcf

I want to save a javascript object of arrays into a dictionary with a list of string in C# through ajax. But I can't figure out the format needed for the object in javascript.

My javascript object is in the format:

```
{
  "foo" : ["abc", "def", "ghi"],

  "foo2": ["123", "456", "789"],

}
```

But the C# data member ends up holding an empty object.

I've also tried

```
[
   {"foo" : ["abc", "def", "ghi"]},
   {"foo2": ["123", "456", "789"]}, 
]
```

My C# datamember is

```
    [DataMember]
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> theDictionary;
```

I have no trouble with saving list of strings or saving other simple javascript objects if I've created the corresponding C# class. Any idea what format is needed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Object pass to ASP.NET Handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13424687/javascript-object-pass-to-asp-net-handler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found my answer here : [Pass a javascript map to json wcf service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001755/pass-a-javascript-map-to-json-wcf-service)

The format I needed was

```
[ 
  { Key: "foo" , Value: ["abc", "def", "ghi"]},
  { Key: "foo2", Value: ["123", "456", "789"]}, 
]
```