# jQuery inserting JSON value to element with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I'm have a little trouble with some jQuery I have been trying to put together today.

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to dynamically have prices inserted into a price button on my page by reading from a JSON feed.

The idea is that there is an empty span that will contain the price. I have given all of the price spans the class `.getPriceNew`. Each span also has an id which is equal to the SKU number for the item like this `<span class="getPriceNew" id="123456"></span>`.

The mechanic is that for each span that has the class `.getPriceNew` the JSON will be queried for the information with the SKU id used as part of the query string.

Here is an example of the code i have tried

**jQuery**

```
$(".getPriceNew").each(function() {
    var sku = $(this).attr("id");
    var priceNew = $.getJSON('/api/MyApi.svc/GetProductBySku/'+sku , function(data) {
            return(data.Variants[0].Price);
            });
    $(this).html("&euro;"+priceNew);        
})
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="getPriceNew" id="123456"></span>
<span class="getPriceNew" id="789123"></span>
<span class="getPriceNew" id="456789"></span>
<span class="getPriceNew" id="654321"></span>
```

**JSON Example**
This is what a single item from the JSON feed would look like - I have filtered it a little
/api/MyApi.svc/GetProductBySku/123456

**Updated with valid JSON**

```
 {
    "Age": {
        "Description": "Age 18+",
        "Thumbnail": "http://someurl.com/productImages/assets/img//icon18.gif"
    },
    "Barcode": {
        "Barcode": "5026555408684"
    },
    "Description": "HTML",
    "Id": 12214,
    "Packshots": [
        "http://someurl.com/productImages/914383/1min.jpg",
        "http://someurl.com/productImages/914383/2med.jpg",
        "http://someurl.com/productImages/914383/3max.jpg"
    ],
    "Pegis": [],
    "Platform": {
        "Button": "Format",
        "ID": 0
    },
    "Publisher": {
        "Description": null
    },
    "Release": "/Date(1364252400000+0100)/",
    "Screenshots": [],
    "Title": "Product Title",
    "Variants": [
        {
            "Id": 22488,
            "MaxOrderQuantity": 3,
            "Presellable": true,
            "Price": 49.97,
            "Sku": 914383,
            "Type": {
                "Description": "Pre-Order"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Vendor": {
        "Description": "Take Two Interactive Software"
    },
    "VideoHTML": "HTML",
    "status": {
        "Response": "product found",
        "Success": true
    }
}
```

I would love some help on this as I am really scratching my newbie head at this stage. I have managed to have console.log output the prices to the log but when I try and insert them back into the spans all I get is [object] [Object].

Comment: You have to serialize to JSON object.  
Look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593046/jquery-json-to-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing

```
$(".getPriceNew").each(function() {
    var sku = $(this).attr("id");
    var priceNew = $.getJSON('/api/MyApi.svc/GetProductBySku/'+sku , function(data) {
            return(data.Variants[0].Price);
            });
    $(this).html("&euro;"+priceNew);        
})
```

`getJSON` returns a `jqXHR` object, which is not what you need. Try this:

```
$(".getPriceNew").each(function() {
    var sku = $(this).attr("id");
    // Save a refference to this span.
    var thisSpan = $(this);
    $.getJSON('/api/MyApi.svc/GetProductBySku/'+sku , function(data) {
            // Request complete, NOW we can use the data we got!
            thisSpan.html("&euro;"+data.Variants[0].Price); 
    });

})
```

The callback is where you want to use the data you get from your AJAX calls. All AJAX methods ($.ajax, $.get, $.post, $.getJSON, etc) will return a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR) object.

Comment: Yes, `jQuery.getJSON` returns a `jqXHR` (which -- side note -- is a `Deferred` implementation). So +1: the updates need to happen in the callback.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip. Seems I am having a little trouble now with my `$(this).html("&euro;"+data.Variants[0].Price);` It does not seem to be setting the HTML for each of the `.getPriceNew` spans.

Is it possible that it `this' is no longer that jquery object?

Comment: Indeed I just checked and now `$(this)` is the JSON and no longer the span selector. Any tips on how to structure this so that I can still insert my price?

Comment: @Jeff this is what I came up with - seems to work so far 

`$(".getPriceNew").each(function() {
    var sku = $(this).attr("id");
    $.getJSON('/api/AthenaService.svc/GetProductBySku/'+sku , function(data) {
            // Request complete, NOW we can use the data we got!
            $(".getPriceNew:first").html("&euro;"+data.Variants[0].Price).attr("class", ""); 
    });

});`

Answer (score 0):

I think your javascript code is correct but your Json output has two errors:
1: "Description":"Some HTML Description here, <- you forgot the closing quote
2: "ID":0}, <- delete the closing brace

So your Json will result like this:

```
{
"Age": {
    "Description": "Age 18+",
    "Thumbnail": "http://url.com/image.gif"
},
"Barcode": {
    "Barcode": "4876416541647"
},
"Description": "Some HTML Description here",
"Id": 12214,
"Packshots": [
    "http: //url.com/productImages/914383/1min.jpg",
    "http: //http: //url.com/2med.jpg",
    "http: //http: //url.com/3max.jpg"
],
"ID": 0,
"Publisher": {
    "Description": null
},
"Release": "/Date(1364252400000+0100)/",
"Screenshots": [],
"Title": "Titleoftheproduct",
"Variants": [
    {
        "Id": 22488,
        "MaxOrderQuantity": 3,
        "Presellable": true,
        "Price": 49.97,
        "Sku": 914383,
        "Type": {
            "Description": "Pre-Order"
        }
    }
],
"Vendor": {
    "Description": "Vendorname"
},
"VideoHTML": "&lt;iframewidth=&quot;725&quot;height=&quot;408&quot;src=&quot;http: //www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLofwA47XDv2_KnfUY52_8mlWg0iUEv8ci&quot;frameborder=&quot;0&quot;allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;",
"status": {
    "Response": "productfound",
    "Success": true
}  }
```

now your code

```
data.Variants[0].Price
```

will return 49.97
to validate Json you can paste it into http://jsonlint.com/ i think is very useful

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm pretty sure I just butchered the JSON when I pasted it in here. I just ran the live JSON through JSONlint and it validated

Comment: I have updated the JSON example to have valid code. Thanks for pointing out the error.