# how to stringify circular JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

Is there build-in method which can stringify a complex JSON object ?

Every time i use JSON.stringfy I get this error: **Converting circular structure to JSON** , and also I need its parser

this an image of my object
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRqKh.jpg

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery json to string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593046/jquery-json-to-string)

Comment: `JSON.stringify` _is_ the built in method, at least in modern browsers.  Can you post the JSON you're trying to stringify?

Comment: JSON is a string of a particular shape. You are trying to stringify a JavaScript object, not a JSON.

Comment: It might be a duplicate of this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861254/json-stringify-deep-objects

Comment: You get the error EVERY TIME you use JSON.stringify? Try it on `JSON.stringify(99)`. If this is your old stringifying-the-DOM question, make sure to take `outerHTML` before trying to stringify, as already described in an answer to another question.

Comment: my problem is that I had nested JSON objects and I can't stringfy this and one of them had HTML tags

Comment: Image of my Object http://imgur.com/s3HbdtQ

Answer (score 4):

You can't exactly convert a circular structure to JSON : there's nothing to describe those relations that can't just be dumped in a finite time.

Alternatives :

- use another format than JSON (for example [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) as suggested by Armadan)
- extend JSON with an additional JSON compatible syntax to describe references
- use a library removing the circular references (producing some JSON but without what can't be stringified). I made such a library : https://github.com/Canop/JSON.prune

Comment: You can also use one of the YAML libraries; YAML, unlike JSON, allows for circular representations.

Comment: This my object before converting :  http://imgur.com/s3HbdtQ
and this after converting : http://imgur.com/ilWUGcU
I had skipped the error which appear but also this lib skipped some data which is important to me

Comment: @MuhammedAbdEl-Wadod And what would you expect ? If you want to restore your object as it was, use a serialization format supporting circular references (for example YAML) not JSON.

Comment: I want to stringfy JSON to store it at **sessionsttorage** and after refresh browser i want to get it back from the **sessionsttorage** and this object creating at the run time and every time i don't know what this object will carry

Comment: and YAML is node.js and I can't use it in app

Comment: @MuhammedAbdEl-Wadod The page I linked you to had a link to a version you can use in your browser

Comment: @dystroy I did so and the result is :
This my object before converting : imgur.com/s3HbdtQ 
and this after converting : imgur.com/ilWUGcU

Comment: @dystroy I think the problem is that there is call for  n.fn.init inside the JSON object

Comment: The problem is the fact that you are trying to serialise DOM objects, such as `option`. You can't do that. Serialise the relevant DOM objects' properties and attributes instead, or `outerHTML` representation, as already noted by @torazaburo.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this little library:

https://github.com/WebReflection/circular-json

It serializes and deserializes otherwise valid JSON objects containing circular references into and from a specialized JSON format.

Comment: This answer needs additional information

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Flatted](https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted). It's tiny and it works very well.
The minified version of it weighs 1KB.

[image]

Here's an example from their docs.

```js
var a = [{one: 1}, {two: '2'}];
a[0].a = a;
// a is the main object, will be at index '0'
// {one: 1} is the second object, index '1'
// {two: '2'} the third, in '2', and it has a string
// which will be found at index '3'

Flatted.stringify(a);
// [["1","2"],{"one":1,"a":"0"},{"two":"3"},"2"]
```

It can then parse the stringified result back if necessary and rebuild the circular references.

```js
var a = [{one: 1}, {two: '2'}]
a[0].a = a
Flatted.stringify(a)
var a1 = Flatted.stringify(a)
var a2 = Flatted.parse(a1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The standard and best solution is [json-stringify-safe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stringify-safe) module.

Here is the usage (described in module):

```js
var stringify = require('json-stringify-safe');
var circularObj = {};
circularObj.circularRef = circularObj;
circularObj.list = [ circularObj, circularObj ];
console.log(stringify(circularObj, null, 2));

// Output:

{
  "circularRef": "[Circular]",
  "list": [
    "[Circular]",
    "[Circular]"
  ]
}
```