# Splitting JSON into string text

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, json, extjs

I have a JSON code coming from `AjaxRequest` and I want it to split the object into a string or array in order for me to manipulate the data. 
Here's my JSON Code

```
[{
    "intAccountId": 2733,
    "strAccountId": "59250-2001",
    "strDescription": "SOIL TEST & GPS SERVICE-WB",
    "strNote": null,
    "intAccountGroupId": 6,
    "dblOpeningBalance": null,
    "ysnIsUsed": false,
    "intConcurrencyId": 1,
    "intAccountUnitId": null,
    "strComments": null,
    "ysnActive": true,
    "ysnSystem": false,
    "strCashFlow": null,
    "intAccountCategoryId": 47
}]
```

The result will something like this.

```
"2733 59250-2001 SOIL TEST & GPS SERVICE-WB"
```

Comment: Using which language? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Check those out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593046/jquery-json-to-string

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object

Comment: Also, isn't the whole point of getting JSON across that you can simply access the elements of the resulting object using things like `jsonobject["strAccountId"]`? Building a string out of that sounds like it should be covered by your most basic understanding of whatever language (probably Javascript? If so, please add that tag to your question) you're using.

Comment: Im using Sencha EXT JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of it, I don't think you want to use `JSON.stringify()`.

I am not sure of your exact output requirements but you could have searched well before asking. Anyways, Assuming you want to do that in JavaScript, here's what you can do.

Let `theResponse` be the variable representing your array.

**1. You need a string made of just the first 3 keys?**

```
var requiredString = [theResponse[0].intAccountId, 
                       theResponse[0].strAccountId,
                       theResponse[0].strDescription
                      ].join(" ");
```

**2. You need a string made of all keys?**

```
var requiredString = [];
for(var key in theResponse[0]){
    requiredString.push(theResponse[0][key]); //obviously there are better ways.
}
requiredString = requiredString.join(" ");
```

How will you handle the `null` values is upto you. May be within the loop you can check if `theResponse[0][key]` is `null` and if true, push a string like "NA" instead.

**EDIT - Retaining the Indicators**
As you asked, Use `JSON.stringify` to convert your object to string containing all keys and values. A little bit of post processing may even give you better structure.

**EXAMPLE**

```
var theOtherString = JSON.stringify(theResponse[0]);
console.log(theOtherString); // your JSON string.
console.log(theOtherString.replace(/"/g,"").replace(/,/g, " ")); //post processed a little.
```

This can go on forever based on what you need.

Comment: I will definitely try that Sir.

Comment: Got it Sir, the Problem is my JSON is dynamic data so the requiredString [theResponse[0].intAccountId] is not applicable approach?

Comment: So I assume the second one worked!

Comment: The Warlock please edit your post and change `JSON.stringity` to `JSON.stringify`

Comment: @Warlock, What if I want to retain the Obeject name like this result for indicator purpose only. intAccountId: 2733 strAccountId: 59250-2001    strDescription: SOIL TEST & GPS

Comment: Then you should better use `JSON.stringify`. Let me edit the answer to show that.