# Returning response data not working with html

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi I am trying to fetch data on same page through ajax.But not success.when I am using html(result) to print success message it's not working .But when I used .text(result) its working but return [object],[object]
Here is my ajax code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#frm_rechargeHistory_process').submit(function(){
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var dataString = 'username='+ username;
        if(username==''){
            alert("Please Fill All Fields");
        }else{
        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "getfoundhistory",
              data: dataString,
              cache: false,
              success: function(result){
                  alert(result);
                  $('#txtHint').html(result);
              }
            });
        }
    return false;
    });
});
```

While  Browser Network response is perfect

```
 [{"Balanceledger": {"id":"2","username":"rawat","amount":"100","reason":"wdeadeses","requestid":"0","approveid":"0","created_date":"2018-11-19 10:41:03"}}].
```

Comment: try to log you response in console  then see your response data

Comment: Kurtis@console data is @@@  0:
Balanceledger: {id: "2", username: "rawat", amount: "100", reason: "wdeadeses", requestid: "0", …}
__proto__: Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are posting the response is coming in the format of JSON. and this needs to be reconstructed in a way that is represented as TEXT or in best cases HTML format

try something like this before replacing the HTML contents

```
var tmpData = JSON.parse(result);
var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(result, null, '\t');
```

Comment: Ahmad Khundaqji@can you post exact code with question .. I am getting JSON.parse(result) error . please let me know what will be exact code

Comment: try the second one then or refer to the following answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9997087/5225589

Comment: Ahmad Khundaqji@data return like that [ { "Balanceledger": { "id": "2", "username": "rawat", "amount": "100", "reason": "wdeadeses", "requestid": "0", "approveid": "0", "created_date": "2018-11-19 10:41:03" }] but I need only data row not json

Comment: Ahmad Khundaqji@you there?

Comment: var formattedJson = JSON.stringify(result, null, '\t');@this is working but this return json array. while  i want print only database result